# Solved - intellij cpu usage over 700% when open specific file

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, axios

I almost crazy intellij usage cpu over 700%.
this case occur when I open specific file.

I solve this problem.
In my case, it was the axios module that caused the problem.

axios using like this. (Using methods dynamically)

```
    const method = type === "new" ? "post" : "put";
    axios[method](url, requestBody)
```

When I opened the file containing this code, the CUP spiked.

Modify the code as shown below and the issue is resolved.

```
    const axiosByType = type === "new" ? axios.post : axios.put;
    axiosByType(url, requestBody)
```

I hope my crappy experience will help you guys.

I solved the problem, and am happy to share it